# Change a static variable in a subclass without changing it in the parent class

Tags: c#, class, static, hierarchy

I want that a.ID() returns 0 and b.ID() returns 1 and here is my code:

```
public class A {
public static int id;
public int ID() {return id;}
}

public class B : A { }

public class Main {
    void Program() { //This executes when I execute the program
        A.id = 0;
        B.id = 1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, this also doesn't work:

```
public class A {
    public static int id;
    public int ID() {return id;}
}

public class B : A {
    public new static int id; //id is actually 1 but ID() is still 0
}

public class Main {
    void Program() { //This executes when I execute the program
        A.id = 0;
        B.id = 1;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Why do you need it to be static?

Comment: Turn your `static int`s into `properties`.

Comment: [new modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) just hides a member. What you need is to override it, but it is static so you can't. Anyway, why would you want to have a static id and an instance getter for it?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Because I have multiple instances of the same class and when I do instance.ID() it should return the ID of the class (so that all instances have the same ID)

Comment: Does it matter what the actual ID number is? Or is it enough that it is unique and all instances of the same type have the same ID? What I mean is, are you married to the values 0 or 1? Or would values like 33554436 and 33554437 work just as well? Does it matter if the ID's change between executions of the program? ie. do you need to store these ID's somewhere? If you can use the latter values and they can change between executions I have the perfect solution to you.

Comment: @Yoshi If you make id static, then you mean it to be the same on all instances of this and all derived classes. So, I think, you have to answer yourself, what you really need: 1) Same id for all instances of this and all derived classes, which I call ClassInheritanceID. 2) Same id for all instances of the same class, I call ClassID. 3) Unique ID per instance, I call InstanceID.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two static variables and one virtual property

```
    public class A
    {
        private static int _idA;


        public virtual int Id
        {
            get { return _idA; }
            set { _idA = value; }
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        private static int _idB;
        public override int Id
        {
            get { return _idB; }
            set { _idB = value; }
        }
    }
```

Or one property and use new keyword to override it

```
    public class A
    {
        public static  int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public static new int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

To test first solution you can try following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A test = new B();

    new B().Id = 3;
    new A().Id = 2;
    test.Id = 1;

    Console.WriteLine(test.Id + " " + new B().Id + " " + new A().Id);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can I still access it with test.Id when I do: a test = new b();? Will it return the ID of b?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `ID` method virtual and override it in the `B` class like this:

```
public class A
{
    public static int id;
    public virtual int ID() { return id; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static int id;

    public override int ID()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is another way to do it that uses [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx):

```
public class A
{
    public static int id;

    public int ID()
    {
        return (int)this.GetType()
            .GetField("id", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .GetValue(null);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public static int id;
}
```

This way, you don't have to override the `ID` method on each subclass. However, you still need to defined a static `id` field in each subclass.

Comment: I also thought of that, but a and b were examples, that would mean that I need the code in every of my classes

Comment: How fast is that with reflection? (Or how much times it is slower than the other approach)

Comment: How many times do you need to access that in a second? You can do a simple test to measure performance using the Stopwatch class.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept these rules:

- The numbers can be anything, ie. any legal `int`

  - They don't have to start at 0
  - They don't have go up by 1 for each new unique type
- The numbers are allowed to change between executions of your program

  - ie. you run your program and type A returns id 33554436
  - You change the program (somewhere else) and rerun, now type A returns id 33554437 (a different value)

then here is a way to get your ID:

```
public class Base
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return GetType().MetadataToken;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to override this property to get unique id's for each type but you can no longer guarantee what the values will be, here's example output from two such derived classes:

```
33554436
33554437
```

If I added a new type between those two and reran, I got:

```
33554436
33554438
```

If you're afraid the constant trip to reflection is going to be expensive here is an alternative declaration:

```
public class Base
{
    private readonly Lazy<int> _ID;

    protected Base()
    {
        _ID = new Lazy<int>(() => GetType().MetadataToken);
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I made a dictionary<type,int> in another class.